# Sort Search Results By Post Type

Tags: wordpress, sorting, loops, search

I am trying to figure out how to sort the search results by post type. I asked the question on wordpress stack exchange and someone tried answering but I don't think they understood what I was trying to achieve. 
-- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72914/search-results-sorted-by-post-types

> For example, when a person searches a term they are taking to the page
>   with the results, all >posts found from all post types are shown but
>   up top there are the different post types name >links that will sort
>   the results and show only the respective post type's post. Right now I
>   have several loops on the search results page for each post type but when I test it, the >loops are all showing the same results even
>   though each loop has a query for a different post type.

My code for the search page - http://pastebin.com/L9zEw1cn

This is a little above the first loop `<?php global $wp_query; $total_results = $wp_query->found_posts; ?> This is the first loop <?php if(have_posts()) : ?> <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post() ?> //My divs// <?php endwhile; endif; ?> <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`

Then the second loop which is the same for all the others except the post type name -- `<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'videos', 's' => $s ); ?> <?php if(have_posts()) : ?> <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post() ?> //My divs <?php endwhile; endif; ?> <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`

How can I fix it so that each loops display the search results for only that post type?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get_posts` for the second loop.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'videos',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  's' => $s
);
$videos = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $videos as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
    // My divs
endforeach;
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Edit: added 'numberposts' to the arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I tried your suggestion but now it is  showing less post than what is actually suppose. About 4 less to be exact. I have it like this - `<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'videos',
  's' => $s
);
$videos = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $videos as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>` then my divs and then to close `<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`  Im doing this for 3 others post types as well and I have a regular loop in the beginning to show all results.

Comment: Use `numberposts` in the arguments. You can read up on how to use get_posts in the codex page.

Comment: I've tried useing the same above code for the other post types and it shows me the same exact posts. I tried changing reset post data to reset query and it gives me the same result.

Comment: I tried this as well but it's not showing no posts `<?php global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&post_type=videos' ); ?>  
 
  <?php if ( $query ) : ?>  
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> `

Comment: I've made some progress, just not quite there yet. Im using this code for the loop - `<?php
global $post;
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'videos',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$myposts = get_posts($args); 
 foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>       //divs <?php endforeach; ?>` it shows the correct post type but it is not showing the correct posts. How can I modify that code so that all the loops are using the same search query/term??

Comment: Try adding the `s` parameter to the query args. e.g. `'s' => get_query_var('s')`

Comment: Wow thanks that worked! The only problem now is that it's not showing all the results related to that post type. For example the video post type there are 9 results shown in but it's only showing 4.

Comment: Actually it didn't work, it's now showing the same posts for all post types but without the s parameter it shows the correct post types.